# conditonal with dlookup value

Tags: vba, forms, if-statement, ms-access, dlookup

I have a subform with a field called "REMAINING PALLETS". In control source I have this look up formula:

```
=DLookUp("[CountofIdPEDIDOSPRODUCTOS]";"[SUMA PALETS]";"[PRODUCTOPEDIDO] = " & [Forms]![PEDIDOS]![PEDIDOSPRODUCTOS]![IdPEDIDOSPRODUCTOS])
```

I have another field in the same subform called "Nº DE PALLETS" and I would like to do the next conditional clause on dirty event in my subform to check if maximum pallets nº is correct:

```
If Me.[nº palets].Value < Me.[Remaining pallets].Value Then
 MsgBox "ESTE PALET SOBRA"  End If
```

and do not add the last record if the conditional clause matches

But It doesn't show any msgbox and the record adds up anyway I don't know why. Is It possible Dlookup control source doesn't allow lf clauses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such expressions are requeried after the code has run.

So include it in your code:

```vb
If Me.[nº palets].Value < Nz(DLookUp("[CountofIdPEDIDOSPRODUCTOS]", "[SUMA PALETS]", "[PRODUCTOPEDIDO] = " & [Forms]![PEDIDOS]![PEDIDOSPRODUCTOS]![IdPEDIDOSPRODUCTOS] & ""), 0) Then
    MsgBox "ESTE PALET SOBRA"  
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I get the same result. The MsgBox doesn`t pop up. Would It be correct add the code in "on dirty" event?

Comment: Most often you would put in the BeforeUpdate of the form or an AfterUpdate of a control.

Comment: At the beginning I put the code on dirty event in the object (a form field). But I relocated the code in after update event, in the subform and It works! Thanks!